# jquery - store data-rowindex value into an array dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to save `data-rowindex` value dynamically into array

```
<tr class="ewTableRow" data-rowindex="1" id="r1_assessment_training" data-rowtype="2">
```

I tried below code. (I am not sure weather below code is correct way or not)?

```
var a = $('#tbl_assessment_traininggrid tr').length;

var row_count = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
        var rowCntrl = $("data-rowindex[i]").val();
        alert(rowCntrl);
        row_count.push(rowCntrl);
    }
```

Comment: a Tr doesn't have a value, what result do you want to be pushed into the array?

Comment: data-rowindex = 1 from HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below answer works for me.

```
$(".ewTableRow").each(function(){
   row_count.push($(this).data('rowindex'));
});
```

Use Jquery function..!

Answer (score 2):

Also please note that if you want to select an element with the variable `i`, then use `$("[data-rowindex=" + i + "]")`

```js
var a = $('#tbl_assessment_traininggrid tr').length;

var row_count = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
  var rowCntrl = $("[data-rowindex=" + i + "]").attr("data-rowindex");
  alert(rowCntrl);
  row_count.push(rowCntrl);
}

console.log(row_count)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl_assessment_traininggrid">
  <tr class="ewTableRow" data-rowindex="1" id="r1_assessment_training" data-rowtype="2"></tr>
  <tr class="ewTableRow" data-rowindex="2" id="r2_assessment_training" data-rowtype="2"></tr>
  <tr class="ewTableRow" data-rowindex="3" id="r3_assessment_training" data-rowtype="2"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use each from Jquery to traverse over the elements and use .data() to get the data from the data  attributes of the element (note: using data helps parse a json string and get a object directly from data attribute, incase you need to save a json string in data attribute), as shown below:

```js
var row_count = [];
    
$(".ewTableRow").each(function(){
  row_count.push($(this).data('rowindex'));
});

console.log(row_count);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr class="ewTableRow" data-rowindex="1"  data-rowtype="2"></tr>
   <tr class="ewTableRow" data-rowindex="2"  data-rowtype="2"></tr>
   <tr class="ewTableRow" data-rowindex="3" data-rowtype="2"></tr>
  </table>
```